# How would you check the last 2 digits of each element in an ArrayList, Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have been given a problem where I have an `ArrayList` containing integers which are between `100-99999999`. The size of the `ArrayList` varies. My task is that I have to search through the `ArrayList` to find elements which have the same last two digits.

For example if the `ArrayList` contains the following: `[100, 7999, 1023, 5556723, 6011, 48823]` and I asked it to print all the elements which end with "`23`"... it should print "`1023, 5556723, 48823`".

What would be the best way to approach this problem? I'm assuming you'd have to use a loop to search each element, however, how would you make sure it only checks the last two digits?

Thank you.

EDIT: I guess you could also filter out any elements which don't satisfy the condition and then just print the remaining elements left in `ArrayList`? I'm not sure if this would be possible.

Comment: You don't really need the "best way" to approach this problem. Just do it any way you can. For checking the last two digits there's plenty of ways, probably the simplest would be to just convert to a String.

Comment: I'm fairly new to programming, I'm not looking for people to write my code.. I just want some sort of guidance as to what could be done to solve it or where to start looking etc.

Comment: Google is the first place you should be looking at.

Comment: Start by writing a method `boolean endsWith(Integer value, String suffix)`. Then use a loop and call this method on each element. If it returns true, print the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could rely on the [`Stream API`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) by converting your `Integer` into `String` and check that they end with a given suffix as next:

```
List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(100, 7999, 1023, 5556723, 6011, 48823);
String suffix = Integer.toString(23);
values.stream()
    .filter(i -> Integer.toString(i).endsWith(suffix))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Output:**

```
1023
5556723
48823
```

---

Or If you are only interested in printing the result it could be also:

```
System.out.println(
    values.stream()
        .map(i -> Integer.toString(i))
        .filter(s -> s.endsWith(suffix))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
);
```

**Output:**

```
1023, 5556723, 48823
```

---

Another approach with a modulo `100` that must be equals to our suffix.

```
int value = 23;
System.out.println(
    values.stream()
        .filter(i -> i % 100 == value)
        .map(i -> Integer.toString(i))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
);
```

**Output:**

```
1023, 5556723, 48823
```

---

> how can you store the filtered values for later use? Instead of
>   printing it.

With a [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) well chosen, for example let's say that you want to get a `List`, the previous code would then be:

```
int value = 23;
List<Integer> result =
    values.stream()
        .filter(i -> i % 100 == value)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(result);
```

**Output:**

```
[1023, 5556723, 48823]
```

Comment: Can you give something simpler for beginners.. like with mathematical operation.. so that they learn modulo as well

Comment: Another quick question, how can you store the filtered values for later use? Instead of printing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modulo operator (%).
This returns the remainder of dividing one number by another. So in your case, you can do **n % 100** to get the last two digits. This can be repeated for any number of digits D with **n % (10 ^ D) == last D digits**.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, there are many ways to approach this problem depending on the depth you are searching for in your project.

The 'best' way is a little too generic in this situation because you haven't specified why you have been given this problem (i.e. for a company? for school? projects? fun?). So without knowing the requirements of how this operation needs to be done, I'll suggest two ways (without providing code) of how you could accomplish determining if a array list of numbers has the same last two digits:

1. You could subtract whatever the number is from each number in the array and then use the modulo operator too see which numbers were evenly divisble by 100. 
   EX: number is 23  ... (1023 - 23) % 100 = 0 but (1021-23) % 100 != 0 so numbers that satisfied this condition would contain those last two digits.

Obviously this method is flawed because if the number was 23 then 23-23 = 0 and 0 % 100 = 0 and so does 24, 25, 26...98, 99, etc. so you would have to account for that situation (i.e., if N < 100)

2. You could convert elements in the array to strings and check the last two chars in each string, i.e. if 1023 was the number, then 23 would be chars 2 and 3 (lol) in the array of chars, which could be found using indexes `length-1` and `length-2`

I hope these ideas help!